# How do you derive the compound pendulum formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator

How do you derive $$T=2\pi\sqrt{I/mgl},$$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $l$ is the length of the [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics))?
Is it even the right formula? How would I derive a compound pendulum formula for a pendulum similar to a clock pendulum with a disc attached to a rod?

Comment: [MIT L24 - Pendulums](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/resources/mit16_07f09_lec24/)

Comment: Be careful. You need specify if $I$ is summed up at the center of mass, or at the pivot.

Comment: @questioner123 Yes, it's valid formula. You can check that by multiplying $ml$ into numerator and denominator of standard formula $$T_{0}=2\pi {\sqrt {\frac {\ell }{g}}}$$. And point-like mass has $I=m\ell^2$ moment of inertia.

Comment: From SHM you have $$\ddot{\theta} = - \left( \tfrac{2 \pi}{T} \right)^2 \theta$$ so find the equations of motion $$\ddot{\theta} = f(\theta)$$ and extract the period $T$ term from it.

Answer (score 0):

How to drive the equation $~T=\ldots~$[image]

you start with the position vectors to the pendulum center of mass $~\vec P_{\rm cm}~$ and the position vector to the disc $~\vec P_d~$

$$\vec P_{\rm cm}=\frac l2\, \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\varphi) \\
    \cos(\varphi) \\
  \end{bmatrix}\quad,
\vec P_d=l\, \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\varphi) \\
    \cos(\varphi) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

from here the velocity of the CM and the velocity of the disc

$$\vec v_{\rm cm}=\frac{d}{dt}\,\vec P_{\rm cm}=\ldots\quad, \vec v_{d}=\frac{d}{dt}\,\vec P_d=\ldots$$

with the kinetic energy

$$T=\frac 12\left(m_p\,\vec v_{\rm cm}\cdot \vec v_{\rm cm}+m_d\vec v_{d}\cdot\,\vec v_{d}+I_{P}\dot\varphi^2\right)$$

the potenzial energy

$$U=m_p\,g\,(\vec P_{\rm cm})_y+m_d\,g\,(\vec P_{d})_y$$

and EL you obtain the equation of motion

$$\ddot\varphi+ \underbrace{\frac{l(m_p\,g+2\,m_d)}{2\,I_P}}_{\omega^2}\,\sin(\varphi)=0$$

for a small angle $~\varphi~$
$$\ddot\varphi+\omega^2\,\varphi=0$$

and with

$$\omega=\frac{2\,\pi}{T}$$

you obtain $~T~$